# Display Multiple images in html table column

Tags: php, html

I have an html row which display multiple images. Sometimes, number of images exceeds the screen width. So I want to display the images in the next row if the `$columnNumber` is a division of 3 (`$columnNumber%3==0`).

I have the following code to display images:

```
 $AllCommentImages = explode(",", $jsonArray[$jsonIndex]['Comment_Image']);
 $html.='<tr><td><b>Photos:</b></td></tr>';
 $columnNumber=0;
 $html.='<tr>';
 foreach($AllCommentImages  as $cimg) 
 {
    $commentmysock = getimagesize($cimg);
    $html.='<td><img style="border:15px solid white;border-radius:15px;" src="'.$cimg.'"'.$this->imageResize($commentmysock[0],$commentmysock[1], 200).'/></td>';
    $columnNumber++;                   
 }   
 $html.= '</tr>';
```

`getimagesize` is used to reduce the size of the images, the images all are in thumbnail size. I have used this code for pdf generation. I am not sure where to use `$columnNumber%3==0` to get 3 images in a row.

Comment: Use bootsrap grid system `<div class="col-4">` 
If you want to make this with table answer commend but you can write less code with bootsrap

Comment: I am using the above code to display table in a pdf(tcpdf). Restricted html access in tcpdf. So can't use bootstrap for this

Comment: is border-radius working ?

Comment: no border radius is not supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should work like this

```
$AllCommentImages = explode(",", $jsonArray[$jsonIndex]['Comment_Image']);
$html.='<tr><td><b>Photos:</b></td></tr>';
$columnNumber=0;

foreach($AllCommentImages  as $cimg) 
{
    if($columnNumber%3==0) $html.='<tr>';
    $commentmysock = getimagesize($cimg);
    $html.='<td><img style="border:15px solid white;border-radius:15px;" src="'.$cimg.'"'.$this->imageResize($commentmysock[0],$commentmysock[1], 200).'/></td>';
    $columnNumber++;
    if($columnNumber%3==0) $html.='</tr>';
}   

while($columnNumber%3!=0){
    $html.='<td></td>';
    $columnNumber++;
}

$html.= '</tr>';
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, but the  page shows errors if the columnNumber is not a division of 3. Error is  Undefined index: rows